# Displaying the photos Set title on flickr photostream

Tags: javascript, jquery, flickr

I'm struggeling a bit with implementing my Flickr photostream on my homepage. I can get the photos to show just fine with paging and all, but I would like to have a caption on each photo with the title of the **set** they belong to.

Doing this:

```
var url = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=62356909@N05&lang=en-us&format=json&nojsoncallback=1";
jQuery.getJSON(url, function (data) { });
```

Doesn't give me any relation to the set the photos belongs to. Also, when calling the photos.getInfo() doesn't contain any info about the set :-/

Does anyone know how to achieve this without making several calls to `collection -> collections -> sets -> photos` ?

Thanks a lot in advance!

All the best,

Bo

Comment: "http" in the URL, not "hhttpp"

Comment: Thanks Pierre, that was a typo when pasting the code ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the .title property of the object you get back contain the title of the set?

- or is that not what you mean?

Comment: Hi Chriztian, nope - the title on the item is the title of the photo itself and not the Photoset it's in :-/ But thanks a lot anyway !

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you will be able to accomplish what you want with just an RSS feed from Flickr.  To get more flexibility (at the expense of more programming complexity), look at the full [Flickr API](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/).  If you're just pulling from your own photostream, you can gloss over authentication, which is the stickiest bit of working with the API.